# "openmp parallel for" crashes when looping over QList<class>

Tags: thread-safety, openmp, qlist

I have a class 'MyFITS' holding a 2D image from a camera with detector 'chip'. And I have a QList holding pointers to a number of images from that camera. Now I want to parallelize a for loop like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int chip=0; chip<n; ++chip) {
    QStringList filenames = getFilenames(chip);
    QList<MyFITS*> images;

    // Read in all images from detector 'chip'
    for (auto &it : filenames) {
        MyFITS *image = new MyFITS(it);
        images << image;
    }

    do_some_calculations(images);

    for (auto &it : images) delete it;
}
```

This works fine without the #pragma directive.
However, with the #pragma directive it crashes in the first line in the second for loop, `MyFITS *image = new MyFITS(it)`. Each thread enters it only once.

I don't understand this. Aren't all variables declared in the for loops private? Which part in this code is not thread safe? I must be overlooking something very simple.

Thank you,

Mischa Schirmer

Comment: We cannot tell you in detail where there error is without a [mcve]. Maybe `MyFITS::MyFITS` or `do_some_calculations` have global side-effects.

Comment: Thank you, Zulan. After commenting out my MyFITS constructor, I found  that the library (CCfits) I'm using to read the FITS images is not thread-safe (and also did not link against a reentrant version of the 'cfitsio' library). After recompiling the libraries my code is now working as expected. For details see here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344726/using-unique-ptrccfitsfits-in-omp-parallel-for-loop-results-in-seg-fault and here: https://github.com/HEROES-GSFC/SAS/issues/125 (turns out I have had the same problem 3 years ago in a different context and forgot about it)